# avconv grayscale and color frame mixing

Tags: ubuntu, webcam, avconv

Have a question - I have purchased a 720p FOSCAM security camera and am ripping still images to my hard disk every several seconds. I have created a shell script that I used with my other Logitech camera.

The camera has night vision / infrared - which is neat, but creates problems with the automated avconv script. For some reason when it shifts to night vision the "format" of the image frames changes, and avconv chokes up because it states format changed to greyscale.

Is there any easy work-around to this problem?

The script that caps the images does the following in the process:

```
convert -strip -type TrueColor webc2-temp.jpeg webc2-temp1.jpeg
```

The script that makes the MP4 files does the following:

```
mv /var/www/Get/WebCam2/Archive/*.jpeg /var/www/Get/WebCam2/MP4/Temp/
convert /var/www/Get/WebCam2/MP4/Temp/*.jpeg -delay 10 /var/www/Get/WebCam2/MP4/Temp/Processing/%05d.jpeg
avconv -r 24 -i /var/www/Get/WebCam2/MP4/Temp/Processing/%05d.jpeg /var/www/Get/WebCam2/MP4/$(date -d "yesterday 12:00" +'%y%m%d')-B.mp4
rm /var/www/Get/WebCam2/MP4/Temp/*.jpeg
rm /var/www/Get/WebCam2/MP4/Temp/Processing/*.jpeg
(ls /var/www/Get/WebCam2/MP4/*.mp4 -t | head -n 1024; ls /var/www/Get/WebCam2/MP4/*.mp4)|sort|uniq -u|xargs rm
chown -R (#####) /var/www/Get/WebCam2/MP4/
```

Here is the errors:

```
*** dropping frame 3289 from stream 0 at ts 3
*** dropping frame 3289 from stream 0 at ts 4
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:1280x752 fmt:gray to size:1280x752 fmt:yuvj420p
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:1280x752 fmt:yuvj420p to size:1280x752 fmt:gray
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:1280x752 fmt:gray to size:1280x752 fmt:yuvj420p
```

UPDATE 7/5/2015

I attempted to convert all the images to PNG when I initally capture them using the following in my "grabber" script:

convert -strip -depth 24 -colorspace YUV -type TrueColor webc2-temp.jpeg webc2-temp1.png

The result is now instead of giving me the greyscale YUV format errors, avconv just skips the frames stating there is an "Error while decoding stream"

```
Error while decoding stream #0:0
 Last message repeated 1109 times
frame=  911 fps= 29 q=28.0 size=   16130kB time=35.50 bitrate=3722.2kbits/s    
Error while decoding stream #0:0
Last message repeated 2234 times
```

Comment: You may have better luck asking on video.SE normally.

Comment: Is your avconv compiles with support of PNG? You have made your files PNG in the second example.